# PrimeFaces: commandButton's validateClient attribute's behaviour

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

In the following simple faces page, I am trying to instruct JSF to NOT to validate the input fields.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:body>
    <h:form id="createPatientForm_id">
        <p:panelGrid columns="3">
            <p:outputLabel value="First Name" />
            <p:inputText id="firstNameInput_id" label="First Name" required="true" requiredMessage="First Name is required"/>
            <p:message for="firstNameInput_id"/>
        </p:panelGrid>
        <p:commandButton value="Submit" ajax="false" validateClient="false" /> 
    </h:form>
</h:body>   
</html>
```

When I click on the 'Submit' button, validation does occur.  Screen shot below:
[image]

I know I have configured `required="true"`.   But, shouldn't the validation be skipped as I have also specified `validateClient="false"`?

What am I missing here?

Comment: validateClient by default is "false"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use immediate="true", perhaps in addition to the Primefaces specific validateClient.  Odds are you have disabled client side validation, but not the server side.